# Set cursor at a length of 14 onfocus of a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, cursor-position, onfocus

Hai Guys,
         I want to set cursor at a position of length 14 on a textbox which will not have a value.. Iknow initially cursor will be at 0 i want it to be at 14

Comment: I believe it's called caret, not cursor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IE use different approach at setting cursor position than Firefox,Opera and Chrome. It's better to make a helper function, which will do it for you. I use this one for own needs.

```
function setCursor(node,pos){

    node = (typeof node == "string" || node instanceof String) ? document.getElementById(node) : node;

    if(!node){
        return false;
    }else if(node.createTextRange){
        var textRange = node.createTextRange();
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd(pos);
        textRange.moveStart(pos);
        textRange.select();
        return true;
    }else if(node.setSelectionRange){
        node.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Last thing, is to call it from your onfocus handler.

Goodluck

Comment: Hai What is node is it textboxId

Comment: node is the DOM instance, but if you need to work with id's, you can add extra "codeline" which will fetch DOM instance for you.

Comment: As DSharma suggested (rolled back the edit, it should have been a comment): In order to make it work for all browsers add timeout to the function call if you want to place the cursor at the beginning of the input text. For Example: `window.setTimeout(function() { setCursor(node,0);}, 1);`

Comment: The 'var' before node is redundant since it's already a function parameter. Great function though.

Answer (score 2):

The moveStart and moveEnd methods expects 2 parameters.
The first parameter is a string (character, word, sentence or textedit).
The second parameter is an integer and refers to the number of units to move.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`$("#textbox").selectionStart=14` might works for Firefox, Opera, Chrome, but not sure for IE

PS: There should be length 14 > characters already in textbox to work properly.

Comment: Mark the textbox will be empty is there any solution

Comment: Yeah, Its for input box and textarea, If yours is Rich Text Box, I am not sure with it then. sorry about that.