# define cursor position in form input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have several input fields with default values. I defined tabindexes to jump from field to field with the tab-button. The problem is that when I get to a field the whole text gets selected, and it is replaced if I start to type. I would like to set the cursor position to the end of the pre-filled text. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

By defining onfocus event on every node. And setting caret position to the end. Because of the default focus/click behavior, setting cursor should be deferred.

```
function setCursorAtEnd(node){
    setTimeout(function(){
         setCursor(node,node.value.length);
    },10);
}

<input onfocus="setCursorAtEnd(this)" value="bla"/>
```

The `setCursor` function you can find in this question: [Set cursor at a length of 14 onfocus of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865563/set-cursor-at-a-length-of-14-onfocus-of-a-textbox/1867393#1867393)

Comment: the function is only working if i go to the field with the mouse. if i switch with the tab button between the fields i get no effect :(

Comment: Try it with timeout. I've fixed the answer. It should help.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you cannot set the cursor position with js, but you could hook a function to reset the prefilled text after the first key press.