# Prevent tab text highlight / disable tab text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a sample form:

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="your name" /><br />

  E-mail:<br />
  <input type="text" name="mail" value="your email" /><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

When you tab to a text input, the value gets highlighted. How can it be disabled?

Any help is appreciated!

Mike

Comment: Take a look here se if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Comment: But that is how we like it. Why don't you?

Comment: @tenshimsm, Great! But I just don't know how to include Mark's code in my form embed code so the cursor be placed at the end of the default value. I wonder if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $yourInput;

$yourInput = $("#your_input");

setTimeout(function() {
  return $yourInput.selectRange($yourInput.val().length, $yourInput.val().length);
}, 10);
```

selectRange function you can find here: [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is the solution. Dirty one:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="a" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        var elm = $(this);
        var val = elm.val();
        setTimeout(function(){elm.val(val);},1);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/S2UPs/

Comment: Hi Naveed, Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

This is working, at least in Firefox. It triggers the "End" key:

```
$('input[type=text]').bind('focus',function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
     e.which = 35; // # key code for end key
    $("input[type=text]").trigger(e);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I need a cross-browser solution. Would you please let me know how to include Mark's code in my form? Or maybe the solution offered on the following reference:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909220/define-cursor-position-in-form-input-field

Comment: Sorry, I've tried jCaret, jquery.caret changed my code and even doing it I didn't work in other browser than Firefox.