# Set cursor position in an input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a lot of search I found the following threads:

[define cursor position in form input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909220/define-cursor-position-in-form-input-field)

[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Unfortunately in none of the posts a complete form embed code or a real example is given. Now I just don't know how to include nemisj's code (on the first link) or Mark's code (on the second link) into my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#site").focus(function(){
    if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
        $(this).val("http://");
    }
});
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="Name" /><br />
<input id="site" type="text" name="mail" value="Website" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder if someone could kindly help me with this as I'm badly stuck!

Many thanks in advance!

Here's the edited code, but it still doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <script>
function setCursor(node,pos){

    var node = (typeof node == "string" || node instanceof String) ? document.getElementById(node) : node;

    if(!node){
        return false;
    }else if(node.createTextRange){
        var textRange = node.createTextRange();
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd(pos);
        textRange.moveStart(pos);
        textRange.select();
        return true;
    }else if(node.setSelectionRange){
        node.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#site").focus(function(){
    if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
    $(this).val("http://");

    var node = $(this).get(0);
    setCursor(node,node.value.length);
}
});
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="Name" /><br />
<input id="site" type="text" name="mail" value="Website" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: createTextRange is an internet explorer only method. Don't use it

Answer (score 4):

Inside your `<script></script>` tag is where your JavaScript goes (although we prefer putting it in a separate file, so that no JavaScript lives on the HTML page itself).

Inside that, you have a call to `$(document).ready()`, which passes a `function() { ... }`. Inside that function is all the code that will be executed when your document has loaded.

Inside ***that*** function you have a call to `$('#site').focus()` which itself provides a function — this time one that will be called whenever the `#site` element gains focus. And presumably that's where you want to change the cursor position.

So, taking the setCursor function from [Set cursor at a length of 14 onfocus of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865563/set-cursor-at-a-length-of-14-onfocus-of-a-textbox/1867393#1867393) you can put that anywhere in your `<script></script>` and then inside that innermost function of yours you can write:

```
if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
    $(this).val("http://");

    var node = $(this).get(0);
    setCursor(node,node.value.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I wish you provided the embed code as I still can't get it to work. I followed your instruction to no aval! :(

Comment: You may want to edit your question to share the code you ended up with.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the error in your `setCursor` method.  The `moveStart` and `moveEnd` methods expect two arguments, the first being the unit it should use.  Also, the end position appears to be relative to the start position.  So I think instead of

```
    textRange.moveEnd(pos);
    textRange.moveStart(pos);
```

you want

```
    textRange.moveStart('character', pos);
    textRange.moveEnd('character', 0);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536623(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this one's easier done than said!

```
<script>
function setCursorInputPosition(e, pos) {
  e.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
}
</script>
<input onfocus="setCursorInputPosition(this, this.value.length);">
```