# Jquery Bind Keyup issue

Tags: jquery

I have a text box that will input a figure in %. What i want to do is that as the user typesin his digits, a '%' sign should get appended at the end. so if some one types in 1.23, what he should see is :- 1% -> 1.% -> 1.2% -> 1.23%. This is what I have written

```
$('#price').bind('keyup',function(){
    val1 = $(this).val();
    val2 = val1.substr(0,val1.length-1);
    $(this).val(val2+'%');
});
```

The problem is the cursor comes in after the % sign appended so after 1% if I type '.' the val1 = "1%." and the final result is 1%%. Some help please? If you can tell me how to put the cursor before % or some other solution to the original issue. Thanks a bunch

Comment: How about adding the % next to the text box? `<input type="text" /> %` - Simple and easy right instead of fiddling the key board events

Comment: @Vega Yes I think that putting it after the text box is easier. but what if I have to put it in the text box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a percent sign to the text field provides a horrible user experience.

You'd better use a background image, or add the percent sign *after* the textbox, optionally positioning it so that it *seems* to be placed inside the box.

Comment: mm.. this is more of a suggestion than answer.. may be it is just me

Comment: @Vega A literal answer can be: "Use `$(this).val(val2.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')+'%');`. I did not post *that* as the answer, because it provides a bad UX. Try it out yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/t4j8C/ (and move the caret to a position other than the end).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's pretty ugly putting things inside of user input. You're better off labeling the field. If you feel you must, look at this question dealing with setting the cursor position.

[Set cursor position in an input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755826/set-cursor-position-in-an-input-text-filed)