# Append brackets () to an input field and placing the cursor in between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-builder

Putting together a very basic query builder using `or`, `not` and `()` operators. I have them appending to an input field though I think it would be beneficial to the user if when the brackets operator button was appended to the input field the cursor would be placed `(here)` ready for the users query.

So far I have:

```
   // query builder functions
$(function() {
  var queryinput = $( "#query-builder-modal .search-box input.querybuilder" );

  $('#query-builder-modal ul.operators li.or').click(function(){
    queryinput.val( queryinput.val() + "OR" );
    queryinput.focus();
  });

  $('#query-builder-modal ul.operators li.not').click(function(){
    queryinput.val( queryinput.val() + "-" );
    queryinput.focus();
  });

  $('#query-builder-modal ul.operators li.brackets').click(function(){
    queryinput.val( queryinput.val() + "()" );
    queryinput.focus();
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me plave the cursor between the brackets in the third click function of this sample code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To place cursor see, for example (have you even tried Google??? it only took me 5 seconds): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755826/set-cursor-position-in-an-input-text-filed or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127221/move-cursor-to-the-beginning-of-the-input-field

Comment: People will suggest solutions that replace the input's value. Note that these break undo/redo. Look into execCommand for an undo/redo compatible way of making input changes. (it's not just for contenteditable!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
$('#query-builder-modal ul.operators li.brackets').click(function(){
    queryinput.val( queryinput.val() + "()" );
    var pos = queryinput.val().length - 1;
    myInput.focus(); /* Seems mandatory for Firefox/Opera */
    queryinput[0].selectionStart = queryinput[0].selectionEnd = pos;
});
```

jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YQEyT/1/)

EDIT: It seems that for Firefox and Opera, you must first `focus()` your input but not on Safari and chrome. I updated the code and the jsfiddle.

Comment: Works fantastic in Chrome, though dosent seem to work in FF, any ideas?

Comment: @DaveHenderson > Sorry I tested on Chrome and Safari, did not think Opera or Firefox would not work. I've updated the code!