# I want to put cursor in beginning of text-box onfocus

Tags: javascript, onfocus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set cursor at a length of 14 onfocus of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865563/set-cursor-at-a-length-of-14-onfocus-of-a-textbox)

I am able to do that in firefox and IE. But for some reason its not working in Chrome and Safari :(

I am simply using below line onfocus

```
$('input:text').focus(
function(){
      document.getElementById('id').setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    });
```

Can someone please tell me how to do similar thing in Chrome and safari?

Comment: I already tried it before posting this question. There are other similar questions too, but both createTextRange and setSelectionRange are not working for me on my safari n chrome.. any suggestions why?

Comment: This should not be closed as duplicate as there are no answers to the question referenced above that solve this issue - that it fails in Webkit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that Chrome (I haven't heard of Safari doing this as well, but I'll take you word for it) kills the selection after the focus event has fired, so you need to add a timer. The following is adapted from my answer here:

[How to place cursor at end of text in textarea when tabbed into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003300/how-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-textarea-when-tabbed-into/6003829#6003829)

However, this generally isn't good usability: it's contrary to what the user expects and removes useful functionality when using the mouse (i.e. the caret going to the location the user clicks). You can probably get around that with some handling of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/z9DhX/1/

Code:

```
function moveCaretToStart(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = 0;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.select();
    }
}

var textBox = document.getElementById("id");

textBox.onfocus = function() {
    moveCaretToStart(textBox);

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        moveCaretToStart(textBox);
    }, 1);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! its working in all browsers now with timeout fn :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. By far the most useful answer I have seen on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Webkit is resetting the caret position as part of the focus event.  You need to defer execution of your script until after the event has fully fired.  Using `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` is good enough:

```
$(":text").focus(function () {
    var input = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        input.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }, 0);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkqGH/1/

Comment: thanks for answering, but its not working yet :( .. my cursor goes at the end of textbox's value when I click inside it(only in chrome and safari). In firefox is working fine as expected.

Comment: @Deepak - I've rewritten my answer.  `setSelectionRange()` works fine, you just need to delay execution to prevent Chrome from resetting the caret position.