# How to place cursor at the end of text after replacing HTML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, content-editor

I have a contenteditable div and trying to replace `<font>` tag with `<span>` tag but after replacing the html using jQuery `replaceWith()` function cursor defaults to the beginning of the text however I want it at the end of the replacing html.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/illumine/Gaqfs/) to reproduce the issue. Let me know if there is any problem reproducing the issue.

Here is demo code gist

```
<div id="test" contenteditable=true>
  <p> <font color="blue">Text to be replaced</font> </p>
</div>
<a id="replace" href="javascript:void(null);">replace</a>
```

JS code

```
$('#test').focus();
$('#replace').on({
  mousedown: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  click: function () {
    $('#test').find('font').replaceWith(function () {
      return '<span style="color:red">' + 'New Text' + '</span>'
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT: Here the problem may sound duplicate but it is indeed different as you see the content gets replaced. I might be replacing the part of that text selected by user and not the entire text. So I need to place the cursor at the end of the html which is replacing the original html.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715762/javascript-move-caret-to-last-character

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1867393/240443) might help (how to set cursor to a position).

Comment: @EvilEpidemic That one is for textarea and does not help in correctly for contenteditable, however I ll have closer look. Thanks.

Comment: Here the problem may sound duplicate but it is indeed different as you see the content gets replaced. I might be replacing the part of that text selected by user and not the entire text. So I need to place the cursor at the end of the html which is  replacing the original html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/96100

Answer (score 8):

You can use this function

```
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

call it as follows

```
placeCaretAtEnd( document.getElementById("content") );
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaqfs/9/)

Comment: Thank you! After hours of trying with different solutions, this is the only one that worked! However, I am using this to highlight text with a different color once it goes past X number of characters. Issue is, as I keep typing, I can see all the text refreshing and that creates a blinking effect. Any way to void that 'lag'?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the `<span>` element by hand using `document.createElement()` and keep a reference to it, you can easily place the caret immediately after it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gaqfs/10/

Code:

```
function placeCaretAfter(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStartAfter(el);
        range.collapse(true);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

$('#test').focus();
$('#replace').on({
    mousedown: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    click: function () {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.color = "red";
        span.innerHTML = "New Text";
        $('#test').find('font').replaceWith(span);
        placeCaretAfter(span);
    }
});
```