# Coloring a single character while typing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a html+ (vanilla) javascript page containing a div (contenteditable). The user writes a word inside the div and this word is compared letter by letter (while typing) with another word.

Let us assume that the second word is JAVASCRIPT. If the user makes a mistake while typing, the wrong letter is colored in red using a style and a span. For example:

```html
JAVAS<span style="color:red">T</span>R
```

The problem is that position of caret is not preserved. I'd like to make the effect completely transparent for the user (he/she can continue typing and each error is marked with red color, while correct characters are left unchanged).

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Could you give us your HTML + Javascript ?

Comment: try creating a fiddler or post code sample

Comment: @akhilaravind Please don't ask for a user to only (or) create code off-site. While it's acceptable, and sometimes helpful, to *also* have code in some off-site location, all questions must be self-contained. That means that the code must be *in the question itself*. For JavaScript/HTML/CSS, users are encouraged to use Stack snippets, which are executable examples within questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Czech this out:

```js
const $c_text = document.querySelector(".checker__inputText");
const $c_word = document.querySelector(".checker__correctWord");

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (
    typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
    typeof document.createRange != "undefined"
  ) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}

const c__word_split = $c_word.innerText.split("");

const checkWord = val => {
  const newVal = val
    .split("")
    .map((ch, i) => {
      if (ch !== c__word_split[i]) {
        return `<span style="color:red">${ch}</span>`;
      }
      return ch;
    })
    .join("");

  return newVal;
};

$c_text.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  this.innerHTML = checkWord(this.textContent);
  placeCaretAtEnd(this);
});
```

```css
.checker__inputText {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.checker__correctWord {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checker__inputText" contenteditable></div>
<div class="checker__correctWord">JAVASCRIPT</div>
```

spcial thanks to [How to place cursor at the end of text after replacing HTML with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852929/how-to-place-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-after-replacing-html-with-jquery)