# Move cursor position to end in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a Twitter like text box. If textbox length exceeds 15 characters they should be displayed in red color. 
So I have appended 2 spans inside div. Whenever the character appended pointer will move to starting position. I want it to be at the end. 
Any one please help me!
Thank-you!

Visit   https://jsfiddle.net/08dmhecp/2/

Or

```js
var tweeet = document.getElementById('tweeet');

tweeet.onkeyup = function(event) {
 var newTweeet = tweeet.textContent;
 if(newTweeet.length > 15){
  tweeet.textContent = "";
  var content = document.createElement('span');
  var extra = document.createElement('span');
  content.textContent = newTweeet.slice(0, 15);
  extra.textContent = newTweeet.slice(15, newTweeet.length)
  extra.style.color = 'red';
  tweeet.appendChild(content);
  tweeet.appendChild(extra);
 } 
};
```

```css
.tweeet {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: blue;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tweeet" id="tweeet" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/08dmhecp/7/) an updated fiddle. I used the method `placeCaretAtEnd(element)` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853375/3789527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for sure, I tested it:

```
var tweeet = document.getElementById('tweeet');

tweeet.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var newTweeet = tweeet.textContent;
    if(newTweeet.length > 15){
        tweeet.textContent = "";
        var content = document.createElement('span');
        var extra = document.createElement('span');
        content.textContent = newTweeet.slice(0, 15);
        extra.textContent = newTweeet.slice(15, newTweeet.length)
        extra.style.color = 'red';
        tweeet.appendChild(content);
        tweeet.appendChild(extra);

        let s = window.getSelection()
        let r = document.createRange()
        r.setStart(tweeet, tweeet.childElementCount)
        r.setEnd(tweeet, tweeet.childElementCount)
        s.removeAllRanges()
        s.addRange(r)

    }   
};
```